# how can mix graph facebook with json blogspot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, blogspot

I have  a code  *javascript* for getting last post blogspot.

please see javacript here> [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnd4rdyL/)
I want to add total share for each posts  using *graph facebook* .

*like this*

```js
function getsocount(url, name) {
  var fbshares;
  $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' + url, function(data) {
    fbshares = data[url].shares;
    $('.facebook .share-count').html(fbshares + ' Shares');
  });
}

$(document).ready(function($) {
  var url = 'http://codepen.io/';
  var name = 'Codepen';
  getsocount(url, name);
});
```

can you help me ?

Comment: What specifically is the problem? What are you expecting to happen that isn't? What have you tried? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: how get share count for every post ?

Comment: @adam how i  get total share for evry post in this javascript; like this http://jsfiddle.net/asfarmohamed33/4n1q95et/1/  ?

Comment: The JS fiddle is returning errors to the console because of the same origin policy. I don't think JSfiddle allows you to access outside urls